# Increase maximum length of query string in Apache

Tags: apache

I'm trying to do a request to a server running Apache 2.4.29 but in the error log (in var/log/apache2/error.log) it shows the following errors:

> [Tue Feb 23 12:10:20.210757 2021] [proxy_fcgi:warn] [pid 17157:tid 140312202696448] [client X.X.X.X:58224] AH02536: couldn't encode envvar 'QUERY_STRING' in 16384 bytes
>
> [Tue Feb 23 12:10:20.210830 2021] [proxy_fcgi:warn] [pid 17157:tid 140312202696448] [client X.X.X.X:58224] AH02536: couldn't encode envvar 'REQUEST_URI' in 16384 bytes

I have configured the file apache2.conf to allow the length I desire (in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf) with the following lines:

```
LimitRequestLine 32000
LimitRequestFieldSize 32000
```

But this doesn't seem to have fixed the issue.

How can I allow this URI to be requested?

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP, so I've removed that tag.

Answer (score 0):

This 16k limit is a compile-time setting of the Apache module proxy_fcgi. Most likely the only way to increase it is to compile the module yourself, which is probably not a trivial thing.

Reference: https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57807